# What is the canonical way for tests in one folder to test functions in another folder in python

Tags: python, pytest

I have a project structure:

```
root
    src
        code.py
    test
        code_test.py
```

How can I call functions in `code.py` from `code_test.py`? `code_test.py` are my pytest tests. I see lots of answers suggesting I make src a package, but what if 'src' shouldn't be a package?!

Feels like I am missing something simple.

Comment: Did you try setting PYTHONPATH to your root directory? This way you can call functions by something like `from src.code import function_name`

Comment: I did, but I can't believe that is the right way to do it. i don't want to pollute the path.

Comment: Its a little bit hacky, but a common solution I've seen is to have test code perform a sys.path manipulation to add the directory. It avoids polluting the path since it is only in effect during the test code, not your outer environment.